# Rendering issue where code snippet joins with info section under question

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, code-formatting, rendering

Noticed that the html rendering for [PostgreSQL - fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586781/postgresql-fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column) code snippet at bottom of question was getting merged with the tags, user info, and action links at bottom of question.

Running OSX 10.7 with stable Chrome (31). Checked on stable Firefox and saw same problem.

[image: Rendering Issue]

Comment: fixed that bug by adding an additional space at the bottom of the post. But this should be checked. Rolled back my edit and now I can't repro it. Damn!